# How to fix org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.PARQUET_FIELD_ID_READ_ENABLED() when running Spark with Delta Lake?

Tags: java, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am following the tutorial [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#language-scala) on how to access delta lake house with spark, but can't seem to get it to work.

I have the following dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Runner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And my code is:

```java
package org.example;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.range(0, 5).toDF();
        df.write().format("delta").save("./tmp/delta-table");
        df.show();
    }
}
```

But when I run this, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigEntry org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.PARQUET_FIELD_ID_READ_ENABLED()'
    at io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension.$anonfun$apply$3(DeltaSparkSessionExtension.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.$anonfun$buildResolutionRules$1(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:174)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.buildResolutionRules(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.customResolutionRules(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$build$2(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.range(SparkSession.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.range(SparkSession.scala:529)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Googling for how to fix did not yield much result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`io.delta.delta-core_2.12.2.2.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/2.2.0) with spark-core version `3.2.0`, but its dependency is spark-core version `3.3.1`.

In your case, it's looking for the [`PARQUET_FIELD_ID_READ_ENABLED`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1047-L1054) configuration parameter, but this has only been introduced in version `3.3.0`. That's causing your issue.

Try using Spark version `3.3.1` :)

Comment: unfortunately that does not seem to work. I changed the version to 3.3.1 <version>3.3.1</version> but the error persists :(

Comment: okay I cleared the dependencies and did a clean build and it now works! Thanks!